# Injecting database values with a non-Drupal application

Tags: 7, database

I have a D7 site which I would like to allow a non-drupal application to be able to inject values into the database. Specifically, I would like to upload a file to a specific field and then associated that field entry with a predetermined user.

The external program is not running PHP either, so it's intended to be an entirely SQL based approach, and not touch Drupal code at all.

Is there a recommended or useful approach to this, for a way to extract the Schema from Drupal, or a CMS-agnostic method of tracking database updates / inserts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

One method would be to use the [Services module](http://drupal.org/project/services) to create a web service that the external program could then communicate with.